# How to go from this summation to this approximation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

https://learn.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/pluginfile.php/194197/mod_resource/content/2/Telephone_numbers.pdf

I'm a high school student investigating on telephone numbers (involution numbers) depicted as T(n). If you read this link, you'll have a good understanding on what I'm talking about. Under the Mathematical Properties subheading in this pdf, there's a section on the summation formula and its approximation. I have no idea how this step works. It mentions that it uses Stirling's approximation. Anyone willing to help? For a certain n value (has to be a natural number) it says it goes from:

$\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]} \frac{n!}{2^k(n-2k)!k!}$

to

$(\frac{n}{e})^{(\frac{n}{2})} \frac {e^\sqrt n}{(4e)^\frac{1}{4}}$

Note that the summation formula has [n/2], but that's because for odd numbers it's [(n-1)/2]. So if n=5 then k=2 is the largest k.
Maybe it's easier to think of it through two separate formula's according to parity, one with [n/2] and another with [(n-1)/2]

I have no idea how the k disappears. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The following holds:
\begin{align*}
T(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{2^kk!(n-2k)!}
\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}n^{\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}n+n^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

The validity of the asymptotic expansion (1) can be obtained in two steps:

- The first step is to derive an *[exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF))* $\mathcal{T}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(n)\frac{z^n}{n!}$.
- The generating function $\mathcal{T}(z)$ encodes the wanted information of the coefficients $T(n)$ which can be extracted using complex analytic methods. Here we can apply a technique from *Hayman* to obtain the analytic expansion.

We start with the first step which is in fact the easy part.

> **Exponential generating function $\mathcal{T}(z)$:**
>
> We obtain from the left-hand side of (1):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathcal{T}(z)}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(n)\frac{z^n}{n!}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{2^kk!(n-2k)!}z^n\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{{2k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{1}{2^kk!l!}z^n\tag{2.2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{2^kk!}\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{z^l}{l!}\tag{2.3}\\
> &=\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\exp\left(z\right)\tag{2.4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2}+z\right)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we take $T(n)$ from (1) and cancel $n!$.
- In (2.2) we write the coefficient of the *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)* in the form $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}=\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}a_kb_l$$
- In (2.3) we write the series as product of two series.
- In (2.4) we use the series expansion $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$.

> **Hayman's method:**
>
> We can now apply to the exponential generating function in (3) the technique published by Hayman (1956) to derive the asymptotic expansion in (1). This is shown in detail in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272904/sum-limits-n-geq-0a-n-fracxnn-exx2-2-implies-a-n-sim-frac1/1274330#1274330)*.

**Notes:**

- Some more detailed information regarding Hayman's method is given in chapter VIII.5 *Admissibility* in *[Analytic combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book070503.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.
- A more general case was proven by *H. S. Wilf* in *[The Asymptotics of $e^{P(z)}$ and the number of elements of each order in $S_n$](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/website/Asymptotics%20of%20exp(P(z)).pdf)*
  from 1986. In this proof we can also find a nice application of the *Lagrange inversion theorem*.